# The enumeration did not return any results on select statement

Tags: c#, sqlite

I encountered a very strange issue on `sqlite`, for summarize: I get no rows when I execute `ExecuteReader()`, but I get the correct rows if I use a `DataTable`.

**Explaination**

First of all, I defined two properties:

```
 private SQLiteConnection _dbConnection;
 /// <summary>
 /// Contain the connection with the db.
 /// </summary>
 public SQLiteConnection DBConnection
 {
    get { return _dbConnection; }
    set
    {
        _dbConnection = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
 }

 private SQLiteCommand _dbCommand;
 /// <summary>
 /// Execute the command for interact with the db.
 /// </summary>
 public SQLiteCommand DBCommand
 {
     get { return _dbCommand; }
     set
     {
        _dbCommand = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
     }
 }
```

in my controller constructor I establish the connection with the `DB` in the following way:

```
public DBController()
{
    DBConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=MyDatabase.sqlite;Version=3");
    DBConnection.Open();

    FillData();
}
```

The method `FillData()` will perform a select on the `DB` for add data to my collections, in that way:

```
public void FillData()
{

  DBCommand = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT * FROM Items", DBConnection);
  DBCommand.Prepare();

  //SQLiteDataAdapter ada = new SQLiteDataAdapter(DBCommand);
  //DataTable dt = new DataTable();

  //ada.Fill(dt);
  //var c = dt.Rows.Count; //<-Get 1 rows and is correct!

  var reader = DBCommand.ExecuteReader();  //Is empty

  while (reader.Read())
  {
  }
}
```

I don't know why happen this, maybe I did something wrong?

Comment: Your `while` loop is empty in that last code snippet so any records you read from the database will just be discarded anyway. You probably do "get" the row(s) you expect but you just throw it/them away. What is the value of the `HasRows` property of that data reader. If it's `true` then there is definitely data.

Comment: The data reader is simply reading the data from the database. If you expect your application to make use of that data then you have to write code to make use of it. What exactly do you expect to be done with the data you retrieved?

Comment: @jmcilhinney I just realized that if I set the breakpoint on reader I get no value, but if I do `Console.WriteLine()` in the loop the data will displaying correctly. This is a bug of sqlite library I suppose. I mean, if I get data, the enumeration on `reader` variable shouldn't be empty, you agree with me?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the SQLite provider. It's you not knowing how a data reader works. You should do some reading on the subject. In short, a data reader contains no data initially and never contains more than one record at a time. The first time you call `Read`, the first record is loaded. Each subsequent time you call `Read`, the next record is loaded. `Read` will return `false` when you have passed the last record. As I already suggested, the `HasRows` property is the way to determine whether there are any rows to read or not.

Comment: you need to store the data from the database in some kind of datastructure - you read row by row, convert each row into some kind instance and store it into a collection that you the query. Thats exacly what datatable does for you - the datatable is the datastruct thats holding the data queried from the DB.

Answer (score 0):

The `DataTable dt = new DataTable();` is used to store all the data from your select.

If you use a reader object, you read results by row and have to "remember" the read data yourself.

You should use `using ( .. ) {}` with database classes to ensure they are closed even if exception happen - much safer and ressourcefriendly this way.

My code uses a OdbcConnection etc - but the classes for SqlLite behave similarily:

```
public List<Item> FillData()
{
    List<Item> myItems = new List<Item>();

    using (var cmd = new OdbcCommand("SELECT Name FROM Items", new OdbcConnection()))
    {
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var i = new Item();
                    i.Name = reader.GetString(0);
                    // or   i.Name = Convert.ToString(reader["Name"])  
                    // or   i.Name = reader["Name"].ToString() 
                    // or  create a Item-Constructor  ... or ....

                    // read all the other attributes into this item

                    // add item to collection to "remember" it
                    myItems.Add(i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return myItems; // or use a class member to store all your items
}
```